# SQL で動的に一定の閾値を超える人数を数える方法

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

以下のように利用日、利用者、利用金額を保有しているテーブルから、月平均利用額が10,000円以上のユーザーの数を動的にカウントするSQLの記載方法がわからず困っています。

| date | id | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-11-01 | 0001 | 2500 |
| 2023-11-10 | 0001 | 10000 |
| 2023-11-29 | 0001 | 3800 |
| 2023-12-15 | 0001 | 3000 |
| 2023-11-01 | 0002 | 8000 |
| 2023-11-05 | 0003 | 5500 |
| 2023-11-22 | 0003 | 8000 |
| 2023-12-05 | 0003 | 5500 |
| 2023-12-23 | 0003 | 8000 |

求めたいのは「月平均利用額10,000円以上」なので、単純に月ごとに利用額が10,000を超えている人数を数えるだけではだめで、例えば上記例では11月時点ではidが0001と0003の2人が月平均10,000を超えているので2ですが、12月時点では0001は19,300 / 2 = 9,350で10,000以下となるので、該当者はid0003のみとなり、求めたい数は1となります。
（平均の基準は一旦過去1年間の平均とします）

欲しいアウトプットは以下のイメージです。
これを標準SQLで出すにはどのようなクエリになりますでしょうか。
使っているのは Redshift で、PostgreSQL 互換の SQL で大丈夫です。

| month | count |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-11 | 2 |
| 2023-12 | 1 |

Comment: @YamazakiKen 求めたい人数について、たとえば id 0004 が 11 月までは一切利用せずに 12 月に合計 10000 円利用していた場合、これは 12 月の人数に数えたいですか？　つまり、月平均というのが「過去 12 ヶ月に渡っての平均」（0004 の場合 12 で割る）なのか「過去 12 ヶ月のうち利用があった月の平均」（0004 の場合 1 で割る）なのかを考えています。

Comment: 「過去 12 ヶ月に渡っての平均」（0004 の場合 12 で割る）、こちらを想定しております。

Comment: なるほど、ありがとうございます。「過去 12 ヶ月に渡っての平均」を求めたい場合は質問文にあるような計算では平均値を出せませんが、そこはシンプルに思い違いだと思ってこちらの仕様で考えますね。

Answer (score 2):

いくつか方法があります。この回答ではデータ分析用の SQL クエリであると割り切って、with 句と[ウィンドウ関数](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Window_functions.html#r_Window_function_synopsis)を使ってクエリを書いてみます。

なお、ある月に 1 回も利用していないユーザーであっても、そこから過去 1 年間の利用金額の平均を取ると 10,000 円を超える可能性があることに注意します。

```sql
-- 利用が無い月も扱うために、最初に月とユーザーを網羅します
with months as (
    select
        year_months.year_month
        , user_ids.user_id
    from
        (select distinct date_trunc('month', u.date) as year_month from usages as u) as year_months
        , (select distinct u.id as user_id from usages as u) as user_ids
)

-- そのあと、月とユーザーごとに利用金額を合計します
, monthly_sums as (
    select
        m.year_month
        , m.user_id
        , sum(coalesce(u.amount, 0)) as amount
    from
        months as m
        left join usages as u on m.year_month = date_trunc('month', u.date) and m.user_id = u.id
    group by
        year_month
        , user_id
)

-- そしてそれぞれの月・ユーザーごとに、その月から過去 12 ヶ月のデータの平均を求めます
, past_year_averages as (
    select
        ms.year_month
        , ms.user_id
        , sum(ms.amount) over (
            partition by ms.user_id
            order by ms.user_id asc nulls last, ms.year_month asc nulls last
            rows 12 preceding
        ) / 12 as amount_average
    from
        monthly_sums as ms
)

-- 最後に平均が 10,000 円以上のユーザーを数えます
select
    pya.year_month
    , sum(case when pya.amount_average >= 10000 then 1 else 0 end) as user_count
from
    past_year_averages as pya
group by
    pya.year_month
order by
    pya.year_month
```

なお、元データのテーブルの名前を `usages` とし、`usages.date` カラムは date 型のカラムとします。date 型でない場合は `to_date` などで適宜変換してください。またクエリ結果の `year_month` も適宜欲しい形にフォーマットしてください。

また、データの最初の方の月は 12 ヶ月分のデータが無いので平均が小さく出てしまいます。この部分を考慮したい場合は 12 で割るのではなく行の数で割るか結果を出さないようにしてしまうか、何かしら改変が必要になります。

Answer (score 0):

(PostgreSQLは手元にないので) 別の SQL (DuckDB)使う方法
DBのインポート・エクスポートに, (簡単のため) pandasを使用
(SQLのみでも使用可能)

- 一旦 月ごとに集計して
- 「0004 の場合 12 で割る」ための, 歯抜けの場所をゼロ埋め

**update**
ゼロ埋め参考: ja.stackoverflow.com [sqlで欠損日付のレコードを補完したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/45070/)

colabで動作確認

```py
import duckdb
import pandas as pd
import io

f = io.StringIO('''
date    id  amount
2023-11-01  0001    2500
2023-11-10  0001    10000
2023-11-29  0001    3800
2023-12-15  0001    3000
2023-11-01  0002    8000
2023-11-05  0003    5500
2023-11-22  0003    8000
2023-12-05  0003    5500
2023-12-23  0003    8000
2024-02-20  0004    9000
''')
df = pd.read_csv(f, sep='\t', dtype={'id': 'unicode', 'amount': int}, parse_dates=['date'])

ndf = duckdb.sql("""
create view if not exists myview(ym, id, amount) as
select t2.ym, t1.id, coalesce(t3.sum_amo, 0)
from (select distinct id from df) as t1
cross join (select unnest(generate_series(start, stop, interval 1 month)) as ym
    from (select min(date_trunc('month', date))as start, max(date_trunc('month', date))as stop from df)) as t2
left join (SELECT date_trunc('month', date) as ym, id, sum(amount) as sum_amo FROM df GROUP BY ym,id) as t3
    on t1.id = t3.id and t2.ym = t3.ym;

select * from myview;
""").df()
print(ndf)

#            ym    id   amount
# 0  2023-11-01  0002   8000.0
# 1  2023-12-01  0002      0.0
# 2  2024-01-01  0002      0.0
# 3  2024-02-01  0002      0.0
# 4  2023-11-01  0003  13500.0
# 5  2023-12-01  0003  13500.0
# 6  2024-01-01  0003      0.0
# 7  2024-02-01  0003      0.0
# 8  2023-11-01  0001  16300.0
# 9  2023-12-01  0001   3000.0
# 10 2024-01-01  0001      0.0
# 11 2024-02-01  0001      0.0
# 12 2024-02-01  0004   9000.0
# 13 2023-11-01  0004      0.0
# 14 2023-12-01  0004      0.0
# 15 2024-01-01  0004      0.0
```

先のデータを用いて平均算出
(SQLの違い: 日付計算に関して SQLによって違いがあるかもしれません)

```py
duckdb.sql("""
SELECT ym, COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT
        strftime(ym, '%Y-%m') as ym,
        "id",
        AVG("amount") OVER (
            PARTITION BY "id"
            ORDER BY "ym" ASC
            RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL 12 MONTH PRECEDING
                      AND INTERVAL 0 DAYS FOLLOWING) asum,
    FROM ndf
    )
WHERE asum > 10000
GROUP BY ym
""")

┌─────────┬──────────────┐
│   ym    │ count_star() │
│ varchar │    int64     │
├─────────┼──────────────┤
│ 2023-11 │            2 │
│ 2023-12 │            1 │
└─────────┴──────────────┘
```

この回答では SQL文は 2つに分かれてるけど, sub query使うなどして合成すれば, 一つにまとめることも可能

Answer (score 0):

SQL1本でやるとするとこんな感じでしょうか。範囲でleft joinするのがポイントです。
※ 日付型は各DBの違いが面倒なので数値で扱ってます。（2023-10-01 -> 20231001）

```
-- 集計年月単位で10000以上だったidの件数をカウント
select trunc(ymdto/100) ym, sum(case when kav >= 10000 then 1 else 0 end) co10kover from (
    
    -- 集計年月、idごとに過去12ヶ月分の合計を取得、12で割る
    select ymdfrom, ymdto, id, sum(kane) kas, sum(kane)/12 kav from (
    
        -- 前年の年月の翌月～今年の年月末日までを対象としてleft join（かなり行数が増えるので注意）
        select p.ymd-10000 ymdfrom, p.ymd ymdto, t.id, t.kane from
    
            -- テーブルに入ってる年月を列挙する
            (select distinct trunc(ymd/100)*100+99 ymd from t) p
    
        left join t on (t.ymd between ymdfrom and ymdto) order by id, ymdto

    ) group by ymdto, id

) group by ymdto
```

確認はmyCompilerでやりました。
https://www.mycompiler.io/view/EFhGgqxzkMz